# Single key not working - not hardware issue

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

So my laptop <kbd>e</kbd> key stopped working. Naturally I figured it was a hardware problem so I plugged in an external keyboard and impressively all keys work except <kbd>e</kbd>. Now I'm baffled. I'm running Windows 7 with latest keyboard drivers.

Comment: Have you installed any program recently that might have hijacked the 'e' key and are using it as a hotkey for an action? For instance, I have a program that swaps my sound from speaker to headset bound to `ctrl + f10`, but I could easily make the hotkey `e` and be unable to use that key for regular use.

Comment: Make and model of laptop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a bit late, but I had the same problem (except it was the "0"-key). The alternate symbols still worked so it wasn't physically damaged. In the end I figured out how to fix it: I changed keyboard layout under Region and Language in the Control Panel to another layout and the key started working. I then switched back to my original layout and the problem was fixed.